# Regular expression for scraping url

Tags: regex

I want to build a regular expression for finding url

Suppose my doc contains two cases of urls like below:

```
<a href="http://www.shopclues.com/phillps-lcd-18.5-193v5lsb23-94.html" class="name" target="_blank">Phillps LCD 18.5 193V5LSB23/94</a>

<a target="_blank" href="http://www.shopclues.com/privacy-policy.html">
```

There are thousands of different url strings. I want only the first case url's in which `class="name"` is present.

So I want url's like the first one : `"http://www.shopclues.com/phillps-lcd-18.5-193v5lsb23-94.html"`

I have written a regular expression but it is giving me all the second case url's.

```
urls = findall(r'href=[\'"]?([^\'" ]+)', text)
```

Comment: Why not just select the `href` of `a` elements with the classname `name`? Why is regex needed here?

Comment: Do you have to use regex?

Comment: Is this a Python question? The one-liner makes it look like it is, and if it is, that might make a difference as in that case you may want to use an HTML parser for the job.

Comment: Yes I want to use regex.

Comment: What is this being used for? You might be able to use [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to grab all `a.name` elements and grab their `href` value instead.

Comment: @fuglede : Don't want to use any external parsing library

Comment: @AnthonyForloney : Yes I know there exists many parsing utilites and libraries. But I want to do it using regex only.

Comment: Why not do this in two steps? First find `/<a[^>]+>/mi`, and then parse for the href string.

Comment: Because you can have anchors without href attribute in a valid html. And I don't see the valor of doing this in one reg exp.

Comment: Okay. Let me try it.

Comment: @NoxNoctis : If you could help me out it. I haven't used regex much in my career.

Comment: That's pretty basic: you find occurences of anchors with one expression, then you loop through them to find hrefs with another. Not a one-liner, but pretty easy to understand and implement. I need to know what regexp engine you are using. It was suggested above that you are using Python...

Comment: Anyway, you need to find `<a[^>]+>` with whatever regexp engine you are using. No capture groups, just these occurences. You then loop through them and do `href\s*=\s*"([^"]+)"`. Here you will have a capture group one, if it matches. And yes, you can have `'` instead of `"`, but, honestly, do two passes with different delimiter, there's almost certainly no need to do that in one expression. Okay, I can write the whole stuff in one expression, this is exactly why I obstain from doing that. Keep it understandable for humans.

Comment: You accepted an answer, which covers only your given input. :) Is it because of a sophisticated regex with lookarounds in it? Should you need a correct answer, that does not depend on the order of the attributes, take a look at what @Organis suggested.

Comment: I tried his answer but I was not getting results which I wanted. I tried the other's regex. It worked. That's not a big issue i guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re
 a = []
r = re.compile('(?<=href=").*?(?=")(?=.*class="name")')
f = open('/****/**/output.txt','r')
for lines in f:
     if len(r.findall(lines)) > 0:
             a.append(r.findall(lines))


print a
```

I hope this will answer you query.Thanks

Comment: So the `class` attribute has to follow `href` attribute. `<a class="name" href="http://www.shopclues.com/phillps-lcd-18.5-193v5lsb23-94.html"  target="_blank">Phillps LCD 18.5 193V5LSB23/94</a>`, which is perfectly valid, will not match.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely correct. But in the question it is no where written that class attribute is before href attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to be as serious as to solve the problem with a single regex. Keep it simple.

```
import re

source = """

<a href="http://www.shopclues.com/phillps-lcd-18.5-193v5lsb23-94.html" class="name" target="_blank">Phillps LCD 18.5 193V5LSB23/94</a>

<a target="_blank" href="http://www.shopclues.com/privacy-policy.html">

"""

urls = re.compile('\<a\s[^\>]+\>', re.MULTILINE)
href = re.compile('href\=\"[^\"]+\"')

alist = re.findall(urls, source)

for anurl in alist:
    if 'class="' in anurl:
        ahref = re.findall(href, anurl)[0]
        ahref = ahref.split('"')[1]
        print ahref
```

Answer (score 0):

I would refer you to here: https://xkcd.com/1171/

And...  recommend you try an html parsing library.  Fortunatly!  There are html parsing libraries for most languages that let you use jQuery / css selectors to get what you want.  For c# there is: https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery

The query would just be "a.name", you'll get back a collection, iterate over it, and get the href attribute.

I've done a fair amount of web-scraping and the jquery like libraries really free you up to focus on extracting the data you need instead of other issues (like crafting regular expressions).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I don't want to use any other library.

Answer (score 0):

I can't post comments because of being new, but this regex seems to be working for me.  I don't know python or how this will functionally work, but the regex matches.  Hope it helps.

https://regex101.com/r/Jt7CED/2

`^(?:<a.*href=(\S+).*class="name".*>|<a .*class="name".*href=(\S+).*>)$`

This regex matches the URL with `class="name"` in two ways.

First, `<a.*href=(\S+).*class="name".*>` will retrieve the URL where the `class="name"` appears after the `href=` attribute.

Second, `<a .*class="name".*href=(\S+).*` will retrieve the URL where the `class="name"` attribute appears anywhere before the `href=` attribute.

The first and second regex pattern are separated by the or/alternative operator `|`.

Comment: Maybe I misinterpreted the question, but I had thought that they wanted help building a regex to find URLs where `href=` and `class="name"` is present, but not match others.